# Power Set of a Power set with the same element

Tags: cardinals

I am working with Power Sets and I am stumped conceptually on a problem that looks as such: A = {a, {a}}.

Find P(P(A)).

I am under the impression the Power set of A would be: {∅ , a}

and then...

P(P(A)) would be: {{∅ }, {a}, {{∅ }} {a, ∅ }}

Which would resulting in a cardinality of 4.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that, if $A$ has $2$ elements, its power set should have $2^2=4$.  (You're missing a couple elements)

Comment: first one is 4, second one is 16.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome @J. W. Tanner. I thought they would be considered to be the same element, thus not counted again for Power Set.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Try to instead look at finding $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}))$ and after you are done, replace $b$ with $\{a\}$.

**Additional hint:**

> So, you should be well familiar with that $\mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}) = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$.  If you still struggle with finding the power set of that result, then try doing something similar as before... naming these something else.  You should be able to find $\mathcal{P}(\{u,v,x,y\})$ and then after you are done, replace $u$ with $\emptyset$, replace $v$ with $\{a\}$, replace $x$ with $\{b\}$, and replace $y$ with $\{a,b\}$ (*and then finally replace $b$ with $\{a\}$ at the end*)

Comment: so {a} and {{a}} are different then in this context? I was under the impression they were the same element, thus the confusion.

Comment: they are different

Comment: @anothercoderbro Absolutely.  $\{a\}$ is not equal to $\{\{a\}\}$.  Just like how $\emptyset$, a zero element set, is not equal to $\{\emptyset\}$ which is a set with one element (*that one element being the empty set, but no less deserving of being considered an element than anything else*) (*which is a strong reminder of another mistake that you seem to have been making*)

Comment: a is an element, {a} is the set with 1 element which is a

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. Thank you @JMoravitz.